# Recyclerview scrolltoposition not working in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I know that there are a lot of posts and questions that are talking about this and fixing this problem.

but I have tried all the solutions that were in front of me and no one of those solutions fixed my problem.

So forgive me :)

I have a `recyclerView` in a fragment using `FirebaseUi adapter`

It has a list of questions I want when a person clicks on a question and gos back again the `recyclerView` scrolls down to the question. So I send the position by intent and received it in `onActivityResult` but it doesn't work.

I have used Handler and used `Timedowncounter` to wait 5 seconds and used

```
mLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView,null,position);
```

and used

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

and used

```
scrollToPosition
```

and even used

```
View recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver()
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        //At this point the layout is complete and the
                        //dimensions of recyclerView and any child views are known.
                        //Remove listener after changed RecyclerView's height to prevent infinite loop
                        recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                });
```

and more and more and no anything happened

So what is the solution ?

Thank u :)

my `OnActivityResult` Code

```
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Constants.TOPIC_INTENT_REQUEST)
    {
      int position = data.getExtras().getInt(Constants.POST_POSITION);
      new Handler().postDelayed(() -> mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position,30), 6000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `onActivityResult()` called

Comment: yes its called on my debugging mode

Comment: post the code for onactivityresult. did you debug and check your statement was reachable?

Comment: yes its reachable .. and i will update the post

Comment: Your if condition is calling in debugging?

Comment: yes its calling and the method also called ..

Comment: is there any solution ..

Answer (score 0):

the solution was by adding

1. `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);`

in onBindViewHolder

this fixed everything

thank u for helping